# Windows Azure is triggering a RuntimeBinderException when I try to set a ViewBag property

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, azure

I'm cheking my service's Intellitrace logs and it's recording several `RuntimeBinderException` when I try to set `ViewBag` properties:

> 'System.Dynamic.DynamicObject' does not contain a definition for 'UserInfo'

It works perfectly when I run the MVC project in my machine.

Is there anything I'm missing here? Why is that?

**EDIT**

Where the ViewBag is set and the exception is thrown:

```
this.ViewBag.UserInfo = new UserInfo()
                {
                    Id = this.DbUser.Id,
                    DisplayName = this.DbUser.Person.FullName,
                    GravatarEmailHash = this.DbUser.Person.EmailGravatarHash,
                    AdministratorId = this.DbUser.AdministratorId,
                    IsOwner = this.DbUser.IsOwner,
                };
```

Comment: Could you show the view code as well as the controller action that is supposed to populate this ViewBag? Also if you had used strongly typed views with view models instead of ViewBag you would never had any problems like this.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, I updated the question with the place where the exception is triggered. Also, I do use strongly typed views, but there are several information common to all views. O put them in the model I would have to make all models to inherit from a base one. I better solution I think is to access the ViewBag through extension methods in both the controller and the view.

Comment: No, you absolutely do not need to make all your view models derive from a common model. You could perfectly fine use child actions. So for example you would have a specific view model for this functionality that you would encapsulate into a child action and you would simply render this child action in your Layout. Then you no longer need to repeat this logic in all your views. As an alternative to child actions you could write a custom HTML helper that will perform this task. Of course if the logic is complex child actions will be better as they allow you completely separate lifecycle.

Comment: No need to use any ViewBag or ViewData whatsoever => all your views could be perfectly strongly typed to view models.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, thanks.. I'll try to figure out the best way to stop using ViewBags. I'll consider your ideas